# Using RestSharp to access Content in RestResponse

Tags: post, restsharp

I'm unable to figure out how to access the content from a RestResponse that requires a POST.  I can view the results in the Visual Studio Debugger but can't access it using "response.content".  Any suggestions?

[Visual Studio Debugging View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8BTu.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Content` is public property, so there's no issue accessing it as `response.Content`. If you have it failing somehow, please post your code and the compilation error.

Comment: The error that I'm getting is "BC30643 Property 'RestSharp.RestResponseBase.Content' is of an unsupported type.

Comment: Here is the code. It shows that I can't access the content property. [VB .NET Code in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVDaI.png)